# Returning index of list in list of lists that contains a specific string

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, return

I think I'm close with this function but I'm having trouble. I need to return the index of the list in a list of lists that contains a particular string. For example, if the list of lists was [['.','c','e','g'],['d',h','t','f']] and my goal was to look for 'c' then the function would need to return 0 since it is in the first list. Or if the goal was to look for 'h' it would return 1 since it is in the second list.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def which_one(lst):
    for row in lst:
        for col in lst:
            if col == 'c':
                return col
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if your list is `[['h', 'i'], ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']]`, and you were looking for `'h'`?

Comment: @nedla2004 I think in that case it should just return 0 since that list would be the first one with h.

Comment: Ok, that is exactly what idjaw's code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a different approach that avoids using two loops. Making use of `enumerate` on your list will only require you to iterate once, where each iteration you will have two values, each representing a running count representing your index, and the next your value. You simply check the character you are interested against the value using `in`, and return the index. Observe the example:

```
def find_index(l, c):
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if c in v:
            return i

res = find_index([['.','c','e','g'],['d', 'h','t','f']], 'c')

print(res) # 0

res = find_index([['.','c','e','g'],['d', 'h','t','f']], 't')

print(res) # 1
```

Just for the sake of adding it, if you wanted to collect all indexes for the character you are looking up, this can be done in a comprehension:

```
def all_indexes(l, c):
    return [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if c in v]
```

Demo:

```
res = all_indexes([['.','c','e','g'],['d', 'h','t','f', 'c']], 'c')

print(res) # [0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful